# Team Foundation Server 2013 Integration Tools?

Tags: tfs, migration, tfs-workitem

I need to bring backlog tasks from a proprietary system to TFS 2013.

I came across an extension called "Team Foundation Server Integration Tools" and "Team Foundation Server SDK" but they support up to TFS 2012.

Is there any product I could use to create backlog tasks in TFS through REST or other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2012 integration tools work fine against TFS 2013, you only need to install the [TFS 2012 Client Object Model](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa). The 2012/v11 adapter works against TFS 2012-2015 and Visual Studio Online.

There are a few features which are unsupported:

- Migration of Test results
- Migration of Work item Tags
- Kanban colum states

In addition to the [items already listed on the Toolkit's page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe).

Alternative products for work item migrations are:

- [Tasktop Sync](https://www.tasktop.com/tasktop-sync)
- [OpsHub Integration Manager](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim)

Should you want to manually code up the migration then the [TFS 2013 Client Object Model](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3278bfa7-64a7-4a75-b0da-ec4ccb8d21b6) will have all the functionality you need. You're looking for the [`WorkitemStore` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore(v=vs.120).aspx) as your main starting point to create and modify work items.

An alternative approach you may want to investigate is to [do an Excel import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx).